# I have several memory questions regarding OS X 10.9.5

Tags: macos, memory, adobe

I have just purchased CS3 and it has been legally transferred to me. Do I have enough memory to handle it? In addition I want to upgrade to Yosemite or El Capitan. Do I have enough memory to do that too?

Also, can I erase photos from iPhoto that I no longer need and will this give me more memory?

Attached is my memory indication.

[image: Activity Monitor OS 10.9.5]

Comment: I stupidly thought I was using OS 10.5.9, transposing the numbers. So, what can I upgrade to? Which one is better?  I guess the answer - can I install CS3 is NO!

Comment: According to [RoaringApps](http://roaringapps.com/) some or most CS3 apps (or at least PS CS3 and Illustrator CS3) run on Yosemite/El Capitan. Please also add your Mac model! Depending on the model some answers may recommend to add some RAM modules.

Comment: To get your Mac model click on the apple in the menubar in the upper left > About this Mac > more Info.. > Overview: (probably) iMac 21,5 " ...the date and the processor type are important to know to answer your question properly

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're running Mavericks (10.9.5) based on the screenshot you provided. That being said, why would you want to *downgrade* to Snow Leopard (10.6.x)? Yes, it is probably a touch faster than Mavericks, but it isn't supported anymore and doesn't have the memory compression feature that might help a bit for a memory hungry application like CS3.

Either way, you have 4GB of RAM which is enough to do basic things on the machine but with CS3 it is probably going to be a potentially sluggish experience if you use it heavily and have more than one application open. I would suggest upgrading your RAM to at least 8GB if you can. What kind of Mac do you have?

Comment: I am sorry, I transposed the numbers. I have OS 10.9.5

Answer (score 0):

[Bing](https://www.bing.com/search?q=adobe%20cs%203%20system%20requirements&PC=U316&FORM=CHROMN) is your friend...

[Adobe CS3 System Requirements](http://www.adobe.com/store/en_us/popup/software/creativesuite/mastercollection/systemreqs.html)

Specifically, regarding the RAM needed:

> 1GB of RAM for DV; 2GB of RAM for HDV and HD; more RAM recommended
>   when running multiple components

Photos in iPhoto are stored on your drive, not continually stored in memory.  This is irrelevant.

You didn't mention what Mac you have.  This is important in determining if you are able to upgrade or not.

Comment: I am sorry, I transposed the numbers. I have OS 10.9.5

Comment: Which Mac model?   Using Terminal issue the command `system_profiler SPHardwareDataType | grep Identifier`  Secondly, why would you want to go from Mavericks (10.9) to Snow Leopard (10.6)?  Or did you mean upgrade to Yosemite (10.10) or El Capitan (10.11)?  Either way, we still need the type of Mac you have.

Comment: Mac Desktop 21.5"

Comment: Can you run the command I provided?  Remember, we're not there to look over your shoulder, so the more info we have, the better.

Comment: I was mistaken and transposed my version number. My OS is 10.9.5. Has anyone with this version been able to use PS CS 5? I can't afford the rental and just on principal, am pretty POed at Adobe for making my 4 year old Mac too young to be able to buy my own Photoshop!

Answer (score 0):

I run CS5 on a 9 year old 4GB machine and it works great on 10.10.  By just limiting what else I run, I am able to keep my memory pressure in the green despite also having the current World of Warcraft client up.  Surprisingly, web apps are total pigs - a well used Youtube window in a web browser can gobble over a gig.

CS3 is built with lower capacity machines in mind, so I think you'll be fine.